# Delete specific line with sed without deleting other lines with same prefix

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to delete lines of a file using sed but I don't want to delete these lines unless the search string matches exactly. ie.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
file="list1"
index=0

while read line ;
  do
    if [ ! "$line" == "@@@" ];
      then
        MYARRAY[$index]="$line"
        #index=$(($index+1))
        let index++
    else
      break
    fi
done < $file

#echo "MYARRAY is: ${MYARRAY[*]}"
#echo "The file: ${index}"

index1=0
for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}"
do
  lineNumber=$((index1 + 1))
  sed -i "/${MYARRAY[$index1]}/d" "$file"
  let index1++
done

sed -i "/@@@/d" "$file"
#remove empty lines
sed -i '/^$/d' "$file"
```

So I have a test file (list1):

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
@@@
line1_1
line2_1
```

And after the script has run I end up with all lines deleted because "line1" and line2" are also matching "line1_1" and "line2_1"

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you anchor your sed pattern match to the beginning and end of the line, then it won't also match substrings. Like so:

```
sed -i "/^${MYARRAY[$index1]}\$/d" "$file"
```

(Escaping the '$' used to anchor to the end of the line since it's in a double-quoted string.)

---

edit: That said, it looks to me like you can replace your entire script with this one-line sed program:

```
sed '1,/@@@/d; /^$/d'
```

That deletes from the beginning of the file to the first line containing '@@@', then also deletes blank lines, and does it all in a single pass.

Comment: Cool - thanks. This was just a test script, I need to do line operations and then delete the line from the feed file only if those operations are successful.  I didn't know how else to do it, but the intention is to put a marker into the text file @@@ and then build an array up to that line in the file, do the operations, and then remove each line and the @@@ marker. The script will then run again on whatever has been added to the file in the meantime.

Comment: @ilium007: Ah, now that's a different question entirely! :-) Consider renaming the file to a temporary name when you begin processing it, letting whatever writes to it create a new empty file, and deleting the temporary file when you're done reading it. There are still race conditions to consider, but that should be closer to a reliable solution.

Comment: Cool, thanks @jamey-sharp. Now to read up on race conditions :)